# How to login to twitter post 1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

This is my old code to login to twitter:

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];
    TWRequest *req = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                         parameters:nil
                                      requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];

// Important: attach the user's Twitter ACAccount object to the request
req.account = self.acAcount;

_strFullName=nil;
self.strUsername =nil;
[req performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData,
                                 NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse,
                                 NSError *error) {

    // If there was an error making the request, display a message to the user
```

It no longer works.

I got this response instead.

So how should I modify the code?

Comment: Can you post the response? I don't see it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the code to:

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"];
```